# Google Spreadsheet API batchupdate formatting won't format DATE

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

The batchUpdate method on the google spreadsheet api allows you to update formatting but I can't seem to make DATE or CURRENCY formats work.

````
sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
            spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEETID.testSheet,
            requestBody: {
                requests: [
                    {
                        repeatCell: {
                            range: {
                                sheetId: batchSheetID,
                                startRowIndex: 3,
                                endRowIndex: 1000,
                                startColumnIndex: 6,
                                endColumnIndex: 8,
                            },
                            cell: {
                                userEnteredFormat: {
                                    backgroundColor: {
                                        red: 1,
                                        green: 0.4,
                                        blue: 0.4,
                                    },
                                    numberFormat: {
                                        type: "DATE",
                                        pattern: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            fields: "userEnteredFormat",
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            auth: client,
        });```

I know I'm targeting the correct cells and columns as this request does in fact change the color of those cells. However I can't seem to make the DATE formatting take effect.
````

Comment: About `but I can't seem to make DATE or CURRENCY formats work.`, I think that in your request body, the date format is changed to `mm/dd/yyyy`. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I am pulling in information and using the API to enter it into a spreadsheet. That spreadsheet uses this information to do some automatic calculations and the date is needed to perform those calculations. The date however is always in a string format when entered ie '01/01/1999   the leading apostrophe makes it read as a string not a date so I need to force the column to format after I input data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the realstionship between `I am pulling in information and using the API to enter it into a spreadsheet. That spreadsheet uses this information to do some automatic calculations and the date is needed to perform those calculations. The date however is always in a string format when entered ie '01/01/1999 the leading apostrophe makes it read as a string not a date so I need to force the column to format after I input data.` and your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?